# how can use python get this url（from wechat）?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, wechat

Here is my Python Code:

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
    testUrl ='http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA4ODIxNjY1OA==&amp;mid=2650747988&amp;idx=1&amp;sn=de85a17895c5e28eb9e4142cdeccbdaf&amp;chksm=88261169bf51987f66f41f5a2dc850af2e30ae77f01c82c45eb4ecd619714daa970b6120c834&amp;scene=27#wechat_redirect'
    
    
    geturl = driver.get(testUrl)
    time.sleep(4) 
    
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    with open('selenium.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
    f.write(html)  
    driver.close()
```

This URL can be viewed in chrome or safari without any problem, but the content that I get with the above code is different. It asks me to provide the cookie so the page can be load. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**There are two ways:**

**use the userdata folder that you used with normal browser**

[image]

```
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\prave\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 3') #give this line only if profile is not default  in the screen should the ending path is default so you don't need this line
```

**Another way to connect is to connect to a already logged in browser session:**

follow below steps :

1. open chrome.exe as :

Connecting to an existing chrome browser from selenium:
close all chrome browsers and then, start the Chrome browser in debug mode by opening cmd and running chrome.exe with — remote-debugging-port argument

```
"<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1557
```

Now open any other browser and navigate to localhost:1557 to check that the browser was indeed opened with that port
Now in selenium code use chrome experimental option to connect to this chrome option

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1557");
browser=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: approach 1 doesn't work, the page I get stills report need cookie to continue load the real text content .

Comment: @AndyYuan are you already logged in that browser ?

Comment: Approach 1 and 2  one works only if , you can open the browser manually , but fails in automation as it uses new chrome profile.

Comment: approach 2 also doesn't work , it report 'cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222'

Comment: did you open chrome with "<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222

Comment: what do you means 'are you already logged in that browser ? '

Comment: That link has session information , it works only if already logged in and the cookie is available. Cookie is available in the user-dir  folder for chrome

Comment: I guess we must provide cookie , as the page prompt/asked. however, even I open the chorme manually and access the url, it shows correctly, so I think I logged in , then I start the script, I still can not get the content as the chrome get

Comment: THen both the mentioned approach should work could you update the step with what you have tried in apporach one and approach 2

Comment: @AndyYuan one more think close all chrome instance before trying approach 1 and approach 2

Comment: all suggestion had tried, but cannot get the whole page, it said the cookie needed.